# How to increment a XSL integer variable

Tags: xslt

**Updated**

I have some huge data, which becomes a large table say **table parent**

each **table parent**'s row will correspond to another table (code given below) say **table child** So when any particular column from the **table parent** row is clicked (hyperlinked) it goes to that part of table **table child**

so i need a counter to differentiate between each **table child**. Please help me figure out this problem. Thanks

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:variable name="counter" as="xs:integer"/>
    $counter=0      <!--here i am assigning 0-->
    <xsl:when test="DBInfo/ORSDBInfo/ORSReposTableTypeInd1/ORSReposColumAllWithTableTypeInd1/@ColumnNm">
        <dd>
            <xsl:for-each select="DBInfo/ORSDBInfo/ORSReposTableTypeInd1">
                <div class="horz">
                <a name="_ORS$counter" href="#_top">ORSReposColumAllWithTableTypeInd1:<xsl:value-of select="$counter"/> </a>
                <table border="1">          <!--above I am using counter to print-->
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Creator</th>
                            <th>LastUpdate</th>
                            <th>UpdatedBy</th>
                        </tr>
                <xsl:for-each select="ORSReposColumAllWithTableTypeInd1">
                    <tr>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="@Creator"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="@LastUpdate"/></td>
                        <td><xsl:value-of select="@UpdatedBy"/>
                    </tr>
                </xsl:for-each>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            $counter=$counter+1     <!--Counter is incremented-->
            <br/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </dd>
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

**More Updates**

So after referring to Wilfred's answer I came up with

```
<a name="_ORS" href="#_top">ORSReposColumAllWithTableTypeInd1_<xsl:number value="position()" format="1" /></a>
```

but now how to use it inside `<a name="_ORS"` so that i get _ORS1, _ORS2, _ORS3 and so on...

Comment: What exactly is your question?  Also when providing a code sample please try and restrict / edit it down to just the relevant parts (and try and format it nicely)

Comment: @Justin: Apologies for the unformatted question, I have edited my question. Please take a look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using:

```
<xsl:number/>
```

See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#number

There are various ways to include it as attributes into your anchor tag.

**Option 1: Using variables**

```
<xsl:variable name="number">
  <xsl:number/>
</xsl:variable>
<a name="{$number}">blabla</a>
```

**Option 2: xsl:attribute**

```
<a>
  <xsl:attribute name="name">
    <xsl:number/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</a>
```

Comment: It helped me partially get integers, but how can it help me get `_ORS1, _ORS2, _ORS3` and so on... ? Please see More updates in my question

Comment: @Wilfres Springer: Please take a look at a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092294/how-to-dynamically-assign-name-and-href-for-anchor-tag-in-xsl) I followed your solution, but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 3):

Use `position()`. Since you are incrementing this once per for-each why don't you simply use `position()`?

```
<a name="_ORS$counter" href="#_top">ORSReposColumAllWithTableTypeInd1:<xsl:value-of select="position()"/> </a>
```

Comment: Hi, I have a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8092294/how-to-dynamically-assign-name-and-href-for-anchor-tag-in-xsl) but the `$counter` does not seem to work for me, from where does this `$counter` is getting referred to?

Answer (score 1):

The notion of an increment is foreign to XSLT as a functional language. However, you could just count the number of preceding elements:

```
<xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::ORSReposTableTypeInd1)"/>
```

Depending on your document layout, this might get more complicated, your milage may vary.

Comment: I did not get it, so you are telling increment cannot be done in XSLT? also how is counting the number of preceding elements going to help me get unique names here `<a name="_ORS$counter"` Note: `8th line`

Comment: That's right. XSLT is a declarative, functional language, not a procedural language like you are used to. It's time you did some reading! Often the solution to a problem in a functional language is very different to the solution in a procedural language - and often it is much simpler, at least once you have grasped the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem and simplest way to solve it is to use Saxon. Here you can find my solution [Incrementing and checking the counter variable in XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608432/incrementing-and-checking-the-counter-variable-in-xslt/13701546#13701546)