# How to dynamically assign name and href for anchor tag in xsl

Tags: xslt

I have a requirement where the xml might have one or more services (name might be different), and I am having a content which should have all of these available services from the xml  something like below

```
<li><a href="#_cms">CMS</a></li>
<li><a href="#_dis">DIS</a></li>
```

but above I have hardcoded the `a` tag content and `href` since I know these are the values, but in real time I would not be knowing these names, so how to set `href` and `anchor tag contents` based on xml values?

So far I got the below `for-each` statement, which gets me all the service names from the xml

```
<xsl:variable name="number">
  <xsl:number/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:for-each select="csmclient/product/domainmetadata/domainmetadata_service">
    <li><a href="#_ser{$number}"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></a></li>
</xsl:for-each>

.
.
.

<!--far below end-->
<xsl:for-each select="domainmetadata/domainmetadata_service">
    <h3>Service Name: <span style="color:#328aa4"><a name="_ser{$number}" href="#_top"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></a></span></h3>
    .
    .
    .
</xsl:for-each>
```

but it does not seem to work, it gives me all my services but the link does not work. Any other ideas?

**Note**: I took help from [this question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952572/how-to-increment-a-xsl-integer-variable) which had a similar requirement.

Answer (score 1):

There is a xslt function `generate-id()` which gives and unique textual identifier for any node in the xml.

http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#function-generate-id

Answer (score 1):

Use something like below, should work

```
<xsl:for-each select="csmclient/product/domainmetadata/domainmetadata_service">
    <li><a href="#{generate-id()}"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></a></li>
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:for-each select="domainmetadata/domainmetadata_service">
    <h3>Service Name: <span style="color:#328aa4"><a name="{generate-id()}" href="#_top"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></a></span></h3>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>  <li><a href="#_ser{$number}"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/><xsl:value-of select="position()"/></a></li>
> ```
>
> but it does not seem to work ...

What you are trying to write is this (not discussing at all if this uniquely identifies the node):

```
<li>
  <a href="#_ser{$number}{@name}{position()}"/>
</li>
```