# Increment counter variable in xsl template call in for each loop

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

This is my XMl:
        I want to print sth like this ,Numbering  as shown 1. 2. only if "name" is ABC . I am having little difficulty in assigning a counter variable and incrementing it and then checking for a certain value in XSLT. 
    Here is my code:

```
<Details>
<name>ABC</name>
<EFFECTIVEDATE>2010-04-30</EFFECTIVEDATE>
</Details>
<Details>
<name>EFG</name>
<EFFECTIVEDATE>2010-04-30</EFFECTIVEDATE>
</Details>
<Details>
<name>XYZ</name>
<EFFECTIVEDATE>2022-04-01</EFFECTIVEDATE>
</Details>
<Details>
<name>ABC</name>
<EFFECTIVEDATE>2022-04-01</EFFECTIVEDATE>
</Details>
<Details>
<name>ABC</name>
<EFFECTIVEDATE>2022-04-01</EFFECTIVEDATE>
</Details>
```

Here is XSL stylesheet:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Details">
    </xsl:call-template name="DetaimTemplate">
</xsl:for-each>

<xsl:template name="DetaimTemplate">

</xsl:template>
```

Expected result

```
  1.ABC
  2.ABC
  3.ABC
```

How can i print like `1.`    `2.` and so on

Comment: Are you transforming your XML to plain text or to HTML or to another XML format? If you only want to number the `Details` elements with `name` as `ABC`, do you want to output the other `Details` elements as well, only without numbers? Or do you want to remove them?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9608432/incrementing-and-checking-the-counter-variable-in-xslt (and other questions found by searching for "counter variables in XSLT"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't mentioned whether your output will be text or xml.
I have provided the solution assuming you are expecting xml output.
I have started from the point where your xslt parser is traversing over each of Details node

```
  <xsl:template match="Details">
    <xsl:if test="name='ABC'">
      <t>
        <xsl:value-of select="count(preceding-sibling::*[name='ABC']) + 1"/>
        <xsl:text>.ABC</xsl:text>
      </t>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could do simply:

```
<xsl:for-each select="Details[name='ABC']">
   <xsl:value-of select="position()" />
   <xsl:text>. ABC&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Of course, you will also need a well-formed input with a root element and a template matching that element to contain the above, before it can work.