# Incrementing an integer in xslt

Tags: xslt, arithmetic-expressions

There is a question with a similar title, but an entirely different question body: [How to increment a XSL integer variable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7952572/430766)

I get a parameter `$level` passed to a template and want to apply templates on `$level + 1`, while `$level` is guaranteed to always be a strictly positive integer. I have this computation right now, but it seems awful. Ther's got to be a better way:

```
<xsl:with-param name="level" select="ceiling(number(concat($level,'.9')))" />
```

This works, but I was wondering if you could directly use [xpath:sum](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-sum) direcly, but I struggle because the literal `1` is not a node on its own.

So, is there a better expression for the `ceiling(number(concat($level,'.9')))` part?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the problem. Your text says "I ... want to apply templates on $level + 1" so I wonder why you do not do that simply with i.e. `<xsl:apply-templates select="foo"><xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level + 1"/></xsl:apply-templates>`?

Comment: @MartinHonnen: Because I'm stupid! Didn't know XSL would understand that and didn't think of trying it. It does what I want. Post an answer, so I can accept it, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> <xsl:with-param name="level" select="ceiling(number(concat($level,'.9')))" />
> ```

**Just use**:

```
<xsl:with-param name="level" select="$level+1"/>
```

Comment: @bitmask: Was a typo -- fixed.